# Left Outer Join Without Duplicate Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

After a lot of searching I could not solve my problem. I have the following tables:

[image]

I want to select all records from my 'product' table. but I have a problem. I got multiple rows from 'product' table when I execute the following query:

```
  SELECT dbo.product.id, dbo.product.name, dbo.product_price.value
          dbo.product_barcode.barcode

FROM dbo.product LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.product_price ON dbo.product.id = dbo.product_price.product_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.product_barcode ON dbo.product.id = dbo.product_barcode.product_id
```

My problem was solved with the following query:

```
 SELECT dbo.product.id, dbo.product.name, dbo.product_price.value
              dbo.product_barcode.barcode

    FROM dbo.product LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.product_price ON dbo.product.id = dbo.product_price.product_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.product_barcode ON dbo.product.id = dbo.product_barcode.product_id 

                      WHERE  (dbo.product_price.id IN
                      (SELECT MIN(id) AS minPriceID
                       FROM      dbo.product_price AS product_price_1
                       GROUP BY product_id)) AND (dbo.product_barcode.id IN
                      (SELECT MIN(id) AS Expr1
                       FROM      dbo.product_barcode AS product_barcode_1
                       GROUP BY product_id))
```

Now I have just one problem. if the 'product_price' table or 'product_barcode' table does not have any record, No records will be returned. I mean if no similar record is found in 'product_price' or 'product_barcode' table, we will not have any record. while we should have records from the 'product' table with null columns of other tables.

Please help me Thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  If you just want rows from one table, why are you bothering with joining anything at all?

Comment: It appears that some products have more than one price or barcode. If you want only the "latest" one then you need a way to determine the order of them. Note that your second query converts the `outer join` operations to `inner join` because the `where` clause _requires_ values from the right-hand tables. If you modify the `where` clause to allow for `null` values, e.g. `or dbo.product_price.id is NULL`, when no matching row is found then you'll get some results. Of course, there is no guarantee that the `min` value is the one you want.

Comment: See msdn for c# linq left outer join syntax : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the conditions are in the WHERE clause - try moving the conditions from the WHERE clause and into each join:

```
SELECT dbo.product.id, dbo.product.name, dbo.product_price.value, 
dbo.product_barcode.barcode
FROM dbo.product
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.product_price ON dbo.product.id = dbo.product_price.product_id
  --moved from WHERE clause
  AND dbo.product_price.id IN (SELECT MIN(id) AS minPriceID FROM dbo.product_price AS product_price_1 GROUP BY product_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.product_barcode ON dbo.product.id = dbo.product_barcode.product_id
  --moved from WHERE clause
  AND dbo.product_barcode.id IN (SELECT MIN(id) AS Expr1 FROM dbo.product_barcode AS product_barcode_1 GROUP BY product_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT dbo.product.id, dbo.product.name, MIN(dbo.product_price.value),MIN(      dbo.product_barcode.barcode)
 FROM dbo.product 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.product_price ON dbo.product.id = dbo.product_price.product_id 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.product_barcode ON dbo.product.id = dbo.product_barcode.product_id 
GROUP BY dbo.product.id, dbo.product.name
```

While the above query should achieve your desired results  - one entry for product with the minimun product_price (if one exist) and minimum product_barcode (if one exist).

I only assumed you wanted this based on the query you were writing. You need to spend more time thinking about the question you are trying to answer.

Joining will multiply your results if more than one entry per join key is present in one of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember this diagram:

[image]

When you are calling `LEFT JOIN` and applying filtering like in the second picture from the top left, you will get only items belonging to the `A` table.

> I want to select all records from my 'product' table. but I have a problem. I got multiple rows from 'product' table when I execute the following query:

Can you try calling `DISTINCT` after `SELECT`, like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.product.id, dbo.product.name, dbo.product_price.value
          dbo.product_barcode.barcode
...
```

Comment: @MohammadGh I agree with you, but that depends actually how much are you concerned about performance. If you want a faster solution than `DISTINCT` you can use `GROUP BY` instead.